# How can I represent a character with an accent in FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I have the following factory which I'd like to use in conjunction with a FactoryGirl.create_list to produce a small dataset with some specific values:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :name do
        forename "Ziggy"
        surname "Stardust"

        factory :sequence_of_names do
            sequence(:forename) do |n|
                forenames = %w(Robert Tommy Tomi Rob Mohammad Amélie Zoo John Robert Brown)
                "#{forenames[n-1]}"
            end

            sequence(:surname) do |n|
                surnames = %w(Thingy Robert smyth Brown Adbul Zoo Cafe Robert Thingy)
                "#{surnames[n-1]}"
            end
        end
    end     
end
```

The forename 'Amélie' has caused an issue:

> syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end ...rt Tommy Tomi
>   Rob Mohammad Amélie Zoo John Robert Brown)

In an rspec file I can simply add the following for the 'é' character to be supported:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

But this doesn't seem to work for a FactoryGirl file; and ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? Do you get a different error message or just still the syntax error you posted?

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? I'm wondering if this is related to https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/192

Comment: Hi carolclarinet - just to clarify, with 'Amélie' in the line it doesn't work and without it there it does work.

Comment: Hi Peter - thanks for the link - I'm using 1.9.3-p0 and I've tried 1.9.3-p448, but no joy there… I'll see if I can get up and running with 2.0.0 :)

Comment: Hi Peter - so I upgraded to ruby 2.0.0-p247 and everything is working :) - I didn't even have to specify the '#encoding: UTF-8' line. Thanks so much, Neil :)